# Is there a word for treating a silly topic with an overly serious tone

Tags: single-word-requests

Facetious is defined as treating a serious topic in a joking manner.

Is there a word for treating a silly topic in an overly serious manner?

For example, "GIF is pronounced with a hard G and this is the hill I choose to die on!" or "Lasagne is the best pasta dish hands down and anyone who says otherwise is dead to me!"

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: In your examples the tone is not overly serious, it is mock serious (jocular).

Comment: _Bathos_ is juxtaposing statements that go from the sublime/grave to the ridiculous, farcical. _Hyperbole_ is extreme exaggeration, but it's usually driven by intense emotion rather than a sense of the ridiculous.

Comment: One speaks of _deadpan_ (or _dead-pan_) humor. The reference is to the face; it means keeping a straight unsmiling ("dead") face while saying potentially funny or ridiculous things.

Comment: Someone's having *a first-world problem*.

Comment: It may be satiire.

Comment: *pythonification* or *pythonization* (noun), *pythonify* or *pythonize* (verb)

Comment: Thanks all. These are very helpful because they introduced me to new words but also helpful in framing it as serious vs mock serious or joking. Is there a way to upvote your comments or give you credit on the website? (sorry, new user)